# Django: How to use model properties within custom methods in a serializer?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializes data for User."""
    url = serializers.URLField(source='profile_url')

    def profile_url(self):
        """Return user profile endpoint."""
        return reverse('user:profile_view', kwargs=self.context.get('id', None))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'url')
```

How can I access User.id within `profile_url`? There doesn't appear to be any `id` parameter within the `context` or at least I don't think I'm accessing properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you may want to change the field on your serializer to be:

```
url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('profile_url')
```

This will give the method profile_url an extra parameter, the object that is being serialized. So in your case, this becomes:

```
def profile_url(self, obj):
    """Return user profile endpoint."""
    return reverse('user:profile_view', args=[obj.id,])
```

Comment: Very nice. Thanks a lot.